# d3 line not drawing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

No matter what I do I can't get a line to show up!

Even trying this doesn't show anything on my graph!

```
var svg, myline;
svg = d3.select(element).append("svg").attr("width", 400).attr("height", 400);
myline = d3.svg.line();
svg.append("svg:path").attr("d", myline([[0, 0], [100, 100]]));
```

I am using d3 from the server:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Because a lot of things has changed, use https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245 as an example (2017).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you should include a `stroke-width` style.

Answer (score 0):

please remove the code from myline and add this and try

```
myline = svg.append('line')
             .attr("x1", 20)
            .attr("x2", 100)
        .attr("y1", 40)
        .attr("y2", 140)
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");
```

hope this helps