# How to show edges in force directed graph using d3.js and Angular?

Tags: angular, d3.js

I'm using Angular 10 and d3 v5 to build a force directed graph. I'm using https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7 as an example to try out and learn. For some reason, the edges in the graph do not show up. I can't figure out why?

```
 this.width = 700 - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = 500 - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    this.simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id((d: any) => d.id))
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
      .force("center", d3.forceCenter(this.width / 2.5, this.height / 1.5));


    d3.json("../assets/miserables.json")
      .then((graph) => {

        let link = this.svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "links")
          .selectAll("line")
          .data(graph["links"])
          .enter().append("line")
          .style("stroke-width", ((d) => Math.sqrt(d.value)));

        let node = this.svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "nodes")
          .selectAll("circle")
          .data(graph["nodes"])
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("r", 5)
          .attr("fill", ((d:any) => this.color(d.group)))
          .attr("fill-copied", ((d:any) => this.color(d.group)))
          .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", (d) => dragstarted(d))
            .on("drag", (d) => dragged(d))
            .on("end", (d) => dragended(d)));

        node.append("title")
          .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

        this.simulation
          .nodes(graph["nodes"])
          .on("tick", ticked);

        this.simulation.force("link")
          .links(graph["links"]);
```

[image]

I do see lines and paths in the SVG but the lines still doesn't show up. Not sure why.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `.style("stroke", "#ccc")` in `link` as suggested here [d3 line not drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826716/d3-line-not-drawing)

Comment: Oh wow. It was that simple. That worked great! thank you